# creating hyperlinks on aframe components

Tags: aframe

I'm creating aframe content/ components and I want to create a "hyperlink" to another website can I attach click event to `<a-image>` tags or do I use `<a-link>` and if so can it also be styled to your liking?

Answer (score 0):

Add a link component to the a-image: https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/.../link.html

Sorry, that should be https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/link.html

Comment: file not found. Also <a-link> component give me a weird display that seems to be uncustomizable

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate however you want visually (e.g., click a box, put a sphere on your head, touch a switch). Whenever you want the link to trigger, all you need to do is:

```
window.location.href = 'https://navigatetohere.com`;
```

Comment: tried using <a-link> and it did not work well. I'm resorting to listeners on the <a-image> tag

Comment: My answer did not mention <a-link>.